# ArcGIS Web JS API "Invalid portal item type 'Map Service', expected 'Web Map'"

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I wouldlike to display the map located at https://cartes.nicecotedazur.org/portal/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=237a9574a4b34ffaba8754a61235e828 using the ArcGIS Web API.

I'm first trying to display it using ArcGIS Sandbox : https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/i

Here's the code sample :

```
  require(["esri/views/MapView", "esri/WebMap", "esri/config"], function (
    MapView,
    WebMap,
    esriConfig
  ) {
    esriConfig.portalUrl = "https://cartes.nicecotedazur.org/portal/";
    var webmap = new WebMap({
      portalItem: {
        id: "b79f6b55f4a0427b8c32ba805fa6e71a"
      }
    });

    var view = new MapView({
      map: webmap,
      container: "viewDiv"
    });
  });
```

But while loading this error message pops up in the console :

```
"Invalid portal item type 'Map Service', expected 'Web Map'"
```

I didn't find any article referencing this error

I tried with two different ids :

- `b79f6b55f4a0427b8c32ba805fa6e71a` which is the web map id
- `237a9574a4b34ffaba8754a61235e828` which is the id found in the url

Answer (score 1):

Is this you actual code?  First problem I see is that this:

```
var view = new WebMap({
  map: webmap,
  container: "viewDiv"
});
```

should be this

```
var view = new MapView({
  map: webmap,
  container: "viewDiv"
});
```

With that, I'm getting a CORS error to that resource.  [Here's a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-js-api-webmap-98zyw).  I'm not sure if that's because I'm using CSB.  I can access the [layer json directly](https://cartes.nicecotedazur.org/portal/sharing/rest/portals/self?f=json&culture=en-us), which means your setup is correct.  But it makes me suspect that if you're getting CORS errors, you may need to [set up a proxy](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/proxies/).

Comment: My bad, indeed it was a mistake. I actually use `var view = new MapView(...)`. About the CORS error, I will look at it and update you